# galaxy tab : saving photo on sd card problem

Tags: android, camera, galaxy-tab

i tried  save photo to sd card and on htc device all ok . I see my photo on sd card and when open i see my photo. But when i tried it on galaxy tab , photo are saved but when i open this photo  i see only black screen. Can any tell how to fix it ?

my code

```
 tempBMP.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, stream);
 log("stream3");
 File saveDir=null; 
 String filename="";
 byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
 try
        {
            if (!saveDir.exists())
            {
                saveDir.mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/ "+""+filename, System.currentTimeMillis()));


            os.write(byteArray);
            os.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

regards, Peter.

Comment: checked but erros not found. on other device are ok . And when i using this code for sending by email . All ok too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why, but this code works for me. Maybe you should use `Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` rather than use "/sdcard/". Try it.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
        dir.mkdirs();

        File out = new File(dir,filename);
        try {
            out.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataOutputStream fo = null;

            try {
                fo = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(out));
                //write what you want to fo
                fo.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: thank, it's work. as a sayd ingsaurabh, we must save image in def folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's the issue of Galaxy Tab itself I think an image can't be viewed if its not on default image folder, if you mount your SDCard on PC then you can easily view these images.

So the overall  idea is that your image is not corrupted its just issue with Galaxy Tab

Comment: thank for the answer. This explains when i sending image by email and i can see than my image. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is throwing null pointer exception which you are handling in catch block generacally and not doing anything to handle it. have a look at it. Can use   Enviroment.getEternalStorageDirectory() for getting root for the sdcard dir.

Comment: i don't have error . Just image on sdcard are black ( black screen when i tried to viewing )